# wordpress jet engine visibility condition based on parent date and time metabox

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, elementor, jet-engine, post-type

im using:

- wordpress: 6.4.2
- jet engine: 3.3.2.1
- jet engine - Custom visibility conditions: 1.1.2
- elementor and elementor pro: 3.18.3

i have a project that is simple and almost done. i've done this already:

1. created two post type: event and design
2. event has a metabox with type "datetime" and enabled "Save as timestamp" and lets name it "deadline_time"
3. created relation between them: each event has multiple designs
4. created a listing for designs to show them

now i'm using elementor "theme builder" -> "single post" to design "design post type" pages (layout) and i have a section that i need to show if "deadline_time" is passed. and also i need to hide an element if "deadline_time" is not passed.

i am familiar with "Custom visibility conditions" but it seems i can't find a way to reach to "deadline_time" meta field.

i can write some code for it but i prefer to go throw the plugin flow.

i tried most of options in "Custom visibility conditions" but i think it's better to go from scratch